# Nature of roots at the biquadratic equation (generalized)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

I need a well defined table / scheme for the nature (real / complex) roots of the generalized biquadratic equation.

$$ax^4+bx^2+c=0;a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},a\ne0$$
$$x^2=z$$
$$az^2+bz+c=0$$
$$x_{1,2}^2=z_1,x_{3,4}^2=z_2$$

Consider $S=z_1+z_2=-\frac{b}{a},P=z_1z_2=\frac{c}{a}$. Now suppose for example that $z_1,z_2<0$. The inequality is equivalent with the system
$$
\begin{cases}
z_1z_2>0 & (1)\\
z_1+z_2<0 & (2)
\end{cases}
$$
because (1) gives $z_1,z_2>0~\lor~z_1,z_2<0$ but (2) excludes the first possibility.

I used the same technique for other cases but I am unsure if my results are perfect or if I'm missing an edge case. Could anyone look over them please?

I have many biquads such as $x^4+2mx^2+m^2-1$ and I need to "discuss" over intervals of $m$ the nature of the roots, that's why I need it. Any suggestion is welcome.

Case I : $\Delta_z<0\Rightarrow x_{1,2,3,4}\in\mathbb{C-R}$

Case II : $\Delta=0\Rightarrow z_{1,2}=\frac{S}{2}$

$S<0\Rightarrow x_1=x_2\in\mathbb{C-R},x_3=x_4=\mathbb{C-R}$

$S>0\Rightarrow x_1=x_2\in\mathbb{R},x_3=x_4\in\mathbb{R}$

Case III : $\Delta_z>0$

**a.** $P<0\Rightarrow x_{1,2}\in\mathbb{R},x_{3,4}\in\mathbb{C-R}$

**b.** $P>0$

$S>0\Rightarrow x_{1,2,3,4}\in\mathbb{R}$.

$S<0\Rightarrow x_{1,2,3,4}\in\mathbb{C-R}$

**c.** $P=0$

$S=0\Rightarrow x_{1,2,3,4}=0$.

$S\ne0\Rightarrow x_{1,2}=0$

- $S>0\Rightarrow x_{3,4}\in\mathbb{R}$
- $S<0\Rightarrow x_{3,4}\in\mathbb{C-R}$

Comment: That's correct, on the assumption that $a,b,c \in \mathbb R\,,\; a\ne 0$.

Comment: @dxiv Those are the conditions, I'll add them to the post. Thank you for confirming + I tested the formulas using GeoGebra with a slider on $m$ and it seems to work.